# How do I create a rewrite rule for URLs with a GET parameter?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite this type of URLS :

http://www.example.com/news/?lang=en

to

http://www.example.com/en-news

Also this should be recursive, meaning that :

http://www.example.com/news/world/?lang=en

should be rewritten to :

http://www.example.com/en-news/en-world/

So far I have this in my .htaccess (modified with arkasha's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482726/335642) ) :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# Rewrite language parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)lang=(\w+)
RewriteRule /?(\w+)/?$ %1-$1 [END]
</IfModule>
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ http://www.example.com/%1-$1? [NC,L,R]` should redirect `/news/?lang=en` to `/en-news` .

Comment: Why do you want `en-` before each directory component?

Comment: @anubhava this is a multilingual site, and that's how the languages are defined in the url.

Comment: ok I understand multilingual part but then URL can be `http://www.example.com/en/news/hello/world/` instead of `http://www.example.com/en-news/en-hello/en-world/`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a rewrite condition to capture the token from the query string, then you can use it inside a rewriting rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)lang=(\w+)
RewriteRule /?(\w+)/?$ %1-$1 [END]
```

That rule set should work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" style file), you should however prever the first option. Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded into the http server and enabled inside the http host. If you decide to use a dynamic configuration file you also need to make sure that it's interpretation is enabled at all and that it is located at the right location.

Comment: I'm restricted to do this in .htaccess, also I should specify that this is a Wordpress site. I included the code (see my updated post), but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Multiple rules are processed from top to bottom. You probably need to move the rule up right after the first one.